# Trying to populate a Grid with rows and columns in response to an event, and then render

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a small single page demo application and in the process of doing so, I have a StackLayout populated with two Grids.

The top Grid contains rows and columns that are already working as I intended, along with a button. Under certain conditions, the button press should populate the lower grid with content that will be generated based on information given in the top grid.

Currently when the program starts, the lower grid contains no rows and columns---it is a "placeholder" Grid. I generate a grid with C# in response to the button press, and want to replace the "placeholder" with that custom generated Grid, and then render it.

Is there a way that I can reassign an existing XAML-defined Grid to an entirely new Grid object, and then render?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of data binding? Generally you're better off defining the second grid in xaml and data binding it to the data objects it needs to show so all your code needs to do is work with data objects.

Comment: Yes I've been using some data binding in the top grid. I was hoping that I could have the lower grid not appear until it became necessary to show it, but I could also just predefine the entire grid and data bind as you said. That is probably the approach that I'll take to move forward with this project now, thanks!